# returning boolean value from Nancyfx

Tags: nancy

I'm having a tiny issue about one particular item regarding Nancy. It should be real simple. I'm just missing something. When I return a property that is a boolean, the value always returns as a string. So, my object has one property setup as "bool valid {get;set;}"

And if my code looks like:

```
    MyObject o = new MyObject();
    o.Valid = true;

    return Response.AsJson(o);
```

the resulting JSON is always {"valid":"true"}. I want {"valid":true}. Is there a way to enforce data types?

Thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Strange, can you use the json.net serializer and see if you still get the issue? This may be a bug with the Simple JSON parser we are using.

Comment: In case you didn't know there is a nuget with the json.net serializer Phil refers to: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Nancy.Serialization.JsonNet